# Python exception not handled when module crashes

Tags: python, exception, crash, imagemagick, wand

I am importing ImageMagick via wand : `from wand.image import Image`
Then I am using it to get data from images :

```
try :
    with Image(filename='./my_image.png') as img:
        sys.stderr.write('SHA-256 message digest for the image pixel stream : ' + img.signature + '\n')
except :
    print("Oops! ",sys.exc_info()[0]," occured.")
```

but with a malformed image ([this one for example](https://github.com/fermads/codepress/blob/master/images/line-numbers.png)) the exception is not handled properly and the script crashes with this message :

> python: ../../magick/quantum.c:216: DestroyQuantumInfo: Assertion `quantum_info != (QuantumInfo *) NULL' failed.

[Here is the doc about Wand Image signature](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.2/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.signature)

Why is the exception not handled properly ?

ImageMagick version I use (I guess it is the default version in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, which I am using) :

```
$ identify --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

As proposed in the comments I am looking for ImageMagick bug :

```
$ identify -debug All line-numbers.png 
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: utility.c/ExpandFilenames/940/Configure
  Command line: identify {-debug} {All} {line-numbers.png}
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6/coder.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7//config-Q16/coder.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.000 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/etc/ImageMagick-6/coder.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/htmlcoder.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/home/username/.config/ImageMagick/coder.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/home/username/.magick/coder.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: coder.c/LoadCoderCache/826/Configure
  Loading coder configuration file "/etc/ImageMagick-6/coder.xml" ...
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Module identify-im6.q16[30840]: module.c/OpenModule/1288/Module
  Searching for module "PNG" using filename "png.la"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Module identify-im6.q16[30840]: module.c/GetMagickModulePath/558/Module
  Searching for coder module file "png.la" ...
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Module identify-im6.q16[30840]: module.c/OpenModule/1297/Module
  Opening module at path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7//modules-Q16/coders/png.la"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Module identify-im6.q16[30840]: module.c/OpenModule/1324/Module
  Method "RegisterPNGImage" in module "PNG" at address 0x7fac6c16f1c0
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Module identify-im6.q16[30840]: module.c/OpenModule/1338/Module
  Method "UnregisterPNGImage" in module "PNG" at address 0x7fac6c16f770
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Policy identify-im6.q16[30840]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/580/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="line-numbers.png" ...
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Blob identify-im6.q16[30840]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2593/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6/magic.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7//config-Q16/magic.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/etc/ImageMagick-6/magic.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/htmlmagic.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/home/username/.config/ImageMagick/magic.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/685/Configure
  Searching for configure file: "/home/username/.magick/magic.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: magic.c/LoadMagicCache/794/Configure
  Loading magic configure file "/etc/ImageMagick-6/magic.xml" ...
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Policy identify-im6.q16[30840]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/580/Policy
  Domain: Coder; rights=Read; pattern="PNG" ...
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Policy identify-im6.q16[30840]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/580/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="line-numbers.png" ...
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Blob identify-im6.q16[30840]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2593/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Coder identify-im6.q16[30840]: png.c/ReadPNGImage/3940/Coder
  Enter ReadPNGImage()
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Policy identify-im6.q16[30840]: policy.c/IsRightsAuthorized/580/Policy
  Domain: Path; rights=Read; pattern="line-numbers.png" ...
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Blob identify-im6.q16[30840]: blob.c/OpenBlob/2593/Blob
    read 3 magic header bytes
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Coder identify-im6.q16[30840]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2042/Coder
    Enter ReadOnePNGImage()
    IM version     = 6.9.7-4
    Libpng version = 1.6.34
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Coder identify-im6.q16[30840]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2055/Coder
      Zlib version   = 1.2.11
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Coder identify-im6.q16[30840]: png.c/ReadOnePNGImage/2085/Coder
      Before reading:
      image->matte=0
      image->rendering_intent=2
      image->colorspace=13
      image->gamma=0.454545
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Coder identify-im6.q16[30840]: png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1651/Coder
    libpng-1.6.34 warning: Image height exceeds user limit in IHDR
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6/locale.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7//config-Q16/locale.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/etc/ImageMagick-6/locale.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/htmllocale.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/home/username/.config/ImageMagick/locale.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/home/username/.magick/locale.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/LoadLocaleCache/1177/Configure
  Loading locale configure file "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6/locale.xml" ...
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6/english.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7//config-Q16/english.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/etc/ImageMagick-6/english.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6-common/htmlenglish.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/home/username/.config/ImageMagick/english.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Locale identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/GetLocaleOptions/824/Locale
  Searching for locale file: "/home/username/.magick/english.xml"
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.010 0.000u 6.9.7 Configure identify-im6.q16[30840]: locale.c/LoadLocaleCache/1177/Configure
  Loading locale configure file "/usr/share/ImageMagick-6/english.xml" ...
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.020 0.000u 6.9.7 Exception identify-im6.q16[30840]: png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1654/Exception
  Image height exceeds user limit in IHDR `line-numbers.png'
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.020 0.000u 6.9.7 Coder identify-im6.q16[30840]: png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1625/Coder
    libpng-1.6.34 error: Invalid IHDR data
2019-05-31T16:20:42+02:00 0:00.020 0.000u 6.9.7 Exception identify-im6.q16[30840]: png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1628/Exception
  Invalid IHDR data `line-numbers.png'
identify: ../../magick/quantum.c :216 : DestroyQuantumInfo:  l'assertion « quantum_info != (QuantumInfo *) NULL » a échoué.
Abandon
```

Edit : I have submitted the problem to the ImageMagick Bugs Forum : https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=36874

Comment: Can you fix the code formatting please

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed it was all over the place I have fixed the formatting

Comment: That's not an exception. Exception handling only handles exceptions.

Comment: Ok, so how would I handle the risk of such a crash in a module in the case of a malformed image ?

Comment: I have added a link to the malformed image in case anyone wants to test the code. The image is a PNG showing a very long list of numbers and is called line-numbers.png

Comment: What version of ImageMagick & environment are you using? This looks like a "double-free" bug in ImageMagick's PNG coder. Try repeating the example without python,  and see what additional info is provided. `identify -debug All my_image.png`

Comment: OK I do this. I add these informations at the bottom of my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yep. Looks like a bug with ImageMagick 6.9.7. The coder should raise an exception that Wand will translate as `wand.exceptions.CoderError: Invalid IHDR data`, but the  IM binary crashes before the exception is emitted. Might be worth heading over to [ImageMagick - Bugs](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=3).

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that.

Comment: But how can I deal with modules bugs from python ? Is there a way to degrade gracefully if a module crashes ? (And not make my script crash)